# How to make the text in terminal (few different command lines) VSCode not blured

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, visual-studio-code

[image]

At the screenshot you may see the difference between normal font display and the terminal.
I've tried to reinstall the VSCode and changed the font-family and font-size.
Zoom+/Zoom-/Zoom reset/ also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal Gpu Acceleration -- Off